# How can I convert this "Tuesday, March 30, 2010 10:45 AM" string to a DateTime practically?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Well,

This is a string I get from a web service:

"Tuesday, March 30, 2010 10:45 AM"

and I need to convert it to a DateTime.

Do you know a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    string strDateTime = "Tuesday, March 30, 2010 10:45 AM"; 

    DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(strDateTime);
```

Answer (score 7):

That's in the "F" format.

It should be parsed easily by

```
DateTime.Parse( s );
```

or by 
DateTime.ParseExact( string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider );

as

```
DateTime.ParseExact( s, "F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Comment: +1 for ParseExact and CultureInfo, for a format like that I would say this is the most correct answer.

Comment: Figuring out what a FormatProvider was was one of the hardest things when starting out.

Answer (score 3):

Not as simple but safer.

```
DateTime dts;
    string strDateTime = "Tuesday, March 30, 2010 10:45 AM";

if(!DateTime.tryParse(strDateTime, out dts))
     Console.WriteLine("not a date!");
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.Parse("Tuesday, March 30, 2010 10:45 AM")
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse may or may not work depending on your Culture settings.

I would recommend using the InvariantCulture, unless you can be sure your computer's culture is set to a culture that works ("en") and not one that fails ("ar").

```
DateTime.Parse("Tuesday, March 30, 2010 10:45 AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Parse()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx